# Loading a project programatically using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Consider the following :

```
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Dance();
```

Is there a way to find the file path (it's inside the same .csproj) in which `Program` is defined using Roslyn? I assume that I have to load the whole project in order for Roslyn to know about the metadata? What is an appropriate way to do this? I saw this :

https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/

and I have the build tools for VS 2013 and 2015. I have referenced Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Engine but VS still can't find a valid reference to MSBuildWorkspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Roslyn itself; specifically, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces`, on NuGet.